# Behavior of IMultiValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I have a DevExpress GridControl  with a style template which has a converter that provides the  cell's background brush property but it is not working properly.

In my GridControl I want to show if a customer attended a seminar so I have a column for the customer and, depending on the selected month, 28 to 31 columns with checkedits in it and the converter returns either a blue brush if there is a seminar on that date or a white brush if there is no seminar.

After one selects the month the GridControl's source is updated and contains only customers who want to attend a seminar in that particular month but when I start the debugging in the convert method I see that it checks also customers that should not be in the source collection anymore and I'm absolutely sure that the convert method gets called after i update the source collection, because I trigger the convert method by giving each column a new header and then resetting the header.

Strangely this works sometimes but not every time.

```
<dxg:GridControl x:Name="seminarGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerList}">
    <dxg:GridControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="customCellStyle" 
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {dxgt:GridRowThemeKey ResourceKey=CellStyle}}"
               TargetType="grid:CellContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{converter:CellColorConverter}">
                        <Binding />
                        <Binding Path="Column.Header" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
     </dxg:GridControl.Resources>
     <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
         <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Customer" Header="Customer" AllowEditing="False"/>
         <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="d0" FieldName="d0" Header="1." Width="27" 
                         CellStyle="{StaticResource customCellStyle}" 
                         EditSettings="{dxe:CheckSettings}"/>
         <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="d1" FieldName="d1" Header="2." Width="27" 
                         CellStyle="{StaticResource customCellStyle}" 
                         EditSettings="{dxe:CheckSettings}"/>
         [...]
         <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="d30" FieldName="d30" Header="2." Width="27" 
                         CellStyle="{StaticResource customCellStyle}" 
                         EditSettings="{dxe:CheckSettings}"/>
    </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
</dxg:GridControl>
```

The convert method:

```
public object Convert(object[] value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value[1].ToString().Equals(string.Empty))
            return Brushes.White;

        var cellData = value[0] as EditGridCellData;
        var customer = cellData.RowData.Row as Customer;

        if (customer == null)
            return Brushes.White;

        var date = int.Parse(value[1].ToString().Split('.')[0], NumberStyles.Integer);
        var result = Brushes.BlueViolet;
        var viewTag = cellData.View.Tag is int
                          ? int.Parse(cellData.View.Tag.ToString(), NumberStyles.Integer)
                          : 0;
        var elements = customer.BookingRelation.Where(p => p.Value.Datum.Day == date && p.Value.Datum.Month == viewTag);


        if (elements.Count() == 1)
            result = Brushes.CornflowerBlue;


        return customer.BookingRelation.Any(item => item.Value.Date.Day == date && item.Value.Date.Month == viewTag) ? result : Brushes.White;
    }
```

How can I solve this problem? The only solution I can think of is to generate the GridControl in codebehind each time the user selects a month but that would be slower than just updating the source collection...

Comment: First of all your approach is really bad (IMO) from a UX perspective. Are you really expecting the end user to go thru 21 columns 1 for each day and check the checkbox? why not use a Schedule control then?.. second, post the code of the converter. Third, instead of a converter you should use DataTriggers in this case.

Comment: Also, this sounds like you don't have a proper ViewModel in order to manipulate this data correctly.. and are trying to use the DXGrid in a winforms way. Please post some code or a screenshot of what it should look like, so we can think of a proper ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I have to await our customer's reaction to the current version. I also decided to color the whole column when there is at least one seminar.

Comment: my point still stands. create a proper ViewModel and don't try to use WPF in a winforms way.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without seeing the code for the converter, but I would be inclined to get rid of the unnecessary MultiBinding and simplify to:

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Column.Header, Converter={converter:CellColorConverterAmended} }" />
```